# How to load data dynamically with recharts correctly?

Tags: reactjs

**Problem:**

I am creating a react application. There I am using recharts to draw a bar chart. But It is not drawing for the data set which is dynamically loaded.

My code is like this.

```
import React from "react";

import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  Cell,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "recharts";

let data = [];
let item;

const data1 = [
  {
    id: 'Page A',  count: 2400,
  },
  {
    id: 'Page B', count: 2210,
  },
  {
    id: 'Page C',  count: 2290,
  },
  {
    id: 'Page D',  count: 2000,
  },
  {
    id: 'Page E',  count: 2181,
  },
  {
    id: 'Page F',  count: 2500,
  },
  {
    id: 'Page G',  count: 2100,
  },
];


const addItemToData = (el) => {
  item = {
    id: el.id,
    count: 2,
  };

  data.push(item);
};

const OffenceStatusChart = ({ offences }) => {
  if (Object.keys(offences) !== 0) {
    Object.values(offences).map((el, index) =>
      addItemToData(Object.values(el)[1])
    );
  }

  if (data1) {
    console.log(data1);
    console.log(data)
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {data? (<BarChart
      width={800}
      height={300}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5,
      }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="id" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip />
      <Legend />
      <Bar dataKey="count" fill="#8884d8" />
    </BarChart>):null}

    </React.Fragment>

  );
};

export default OffenceStatusChart;
```

In here data1 array data set is working correctly but for data array data set it showing the chart as like this.

[image]

when I hover over the graph it shows like this.
[image]

In the inspect window is showing like this.

[image]

the data array is like this.

[image]

the data1 array is like this.

[image]

Both arrays are in same format but for the data array it is not drawing the bar char but for data1 array. I tried to realize so much what is this error but I was completely helpless so that is why I asked it here. So if someone can help me to solve this issue it really really grateful. Thank you

Comment: 1. Do you see any tooltip showing up, while hovering on the current chart?
2. Do you see any elements on the developer tools elements tab?

Comment: @user2063635 I updated the question with how it shows when I hover the graph.

Comment: Such curve can be observed when hovering, when data array is empty.
Can you add a console statement for data just before return statement and check if it displays the array of objects? Can you create a code pen for your code?

Comment: you may instead try to implement reach hooks for the data values to be effectively picked  in the chart